# Problema al importar Axios en React

Tags: reactjs, axios

**Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de importar axios en un proyecto en React. Resulta que al importarlo al proyecto me sale este error:**

Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js 11:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters'
Did you mean './http'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js 13:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
- install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js 19:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js 21:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
- install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js 17:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 1:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\follow-redirects'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 5:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\follow-redirects'
Did you mean './http'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 7:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\follow-redirects'
Did you mean './https'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
- install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 9:15-41

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\follow-redirects'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 11:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce-Laravel-React\front\node_modules\follow-redirects'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
- install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }

---

Instale axios con:

```
npm install axios
```

Y como no funcionó, probé con:

```
npm install axios --save
```

Pero tampoco funcionó.

así lo importo en el proyecto:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

Estoy utilizando React 18.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.